# Convert ajax script from 1.8.3 jquery to 1.9

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination

I'm trying to use pagination script. But I use jQuery ver. 1.9.1 on website, and this script works just with version 1.8.3... I'm new to jQuery, and I don't know how to fix it. I think, there is some syntax problem with ajax and ParseInt...

[jsFiddle EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/FdkXc/)

[Original script](http://onlinewebapplication.com/pagination-jquery-php-ajax-mysql/)

jQuery

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
          function loading_show(){
              $('#loading').html("<img src='images/loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
          }
          function loading_hide(){
              $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
          }                
          function loadData(page){
              loading_show();                    
              $.ajax
              ({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "load_data.php",
                  data: "page="+page,
                  success: function(msg)
                  {
                      $("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                      {
                          loading_hide();
                          $("#container").html(msg);
                      });
                  }
              });
          }
          loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
          $('#container .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
              var page = $(this).attr('p');
              loadData(page);

          });           
          $('#go_btn').live('click',function(){
              var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
              var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
              if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
                  loadData(page);
              }else{
                  alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
                  $('.goto').val("").focus();
                  return false;
              }

          });
      });
```

Comment: You'll need to replace live() with on(), otherwise it looks like the rest of the code should be valid in 1.9.1 ?

Comment: I can not make working example in jsFiddle, but I think there is some other problem with ajax. Becouse this jquery script can not load informations from php script...

Comment: Why are you doing ajaxComplete inside of an ajax success?

Comment: I'm new to jQuery. I found this script on some page... But I think, that steps are : start Ajax > show loading animation > on ajaxComplete hide loading animation > show loaded informations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to fix anything, you can still use the 1.8.3 code with the new version by using the [jQuery Migrate plugin](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/02/16/jquery-migrate-1-1-1-released/). Even in the Fiddle on the left hand side, you have the option to include the Migrate plugin.

Using the plugin is easy; just include it immediately after the script tag for jQuery, for example.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>
```

For more information, see the [jQuery Migrate documentation](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme).

Comment: Thanx Palash, you are right, it works. But, it is another big script on page. I would like to find some clear solution. :)

Comment: The file is not that big. The minified version is just 8KB :)

Comment: Yes it works realy fine... but, maybe there is some solution with a few letter change. :)

Comment: latest v of 1.2.1 can be used but yes its IE support can be a mess :P
http://plugins.jquery.com/migrate/